# changing notification sound of a different app

Tags: android, audio, android-notifications

i'm trying to catch all the notifications and play a specific sound according to the contact of the notification.
myNotificationListener  wait for incoming  StatusBarNotification  and deciding what sound to play then sending it to myCustomNotification . where it sending the Notification. 
currently my code goes like this:

```
 public class myNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        if (isPreferenceOn()) {
            String pack = sbn.getPackageName();

//         take Notification details
            Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
            String title = extras.getString("android.title");
            String text = extras.getString("android.text");
            String app = sbn.getPackageName();
            int id = sbn.getId();

            Log.i("Text", "" + text);


                //find sounds by trigers
                Uri DoublesoundUri = null;
                if (Double != null)
                    DoublesoundUri = SoundResolver.getSound(text );
                Uri SinglesoundUri = null;
                if (Single != null)
                    SinglesoundUri = SoundResolver.getSound(text );

                //decide witch sound to play
                if (DoublesoundUri != null) {

                    not.sound = DoublesoundUri;

                    //new myCustomNotification(DoublesoundUri, Double, context);
                } else if (SinglesoundUri != null) {

                    not.sound = SinglesoundUri;

                    //   new myCustomNotification(SinglesoundUri, Single, context);
                }



        }
    }
```

and there is the class of my custom Notification

```
public class myCustomNotification {


    myCustomNotification(Uri soundUri,String text, Context context) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSound(soundUri)
                         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_white_24dp)
                          .setContentTitle(text)
                            .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

        // Sets an ID for the notification
        int mNotificationId = 2580;

// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }


}
```

the problem is that i'm getting 2 sounds instead of one: 
1. my custom sound
2. the original sound

is there any way to override the original sound? that i will hear only the custom  one.

i have trid:

```
            sbn.getNotification().sound=SinglesoundUri;
```

but it doesn't play the sound, actually  `sbn.getNotification().sound==null` when the StatusBarNotification  is cached.

Answer (score 0):

you must also override the default sound by setting the notification defaults
use code below:

```
String sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notifysnd) ;

myCustomNotification(Uri soundUri,String text, Context context) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)//it replaces your default voice
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_white_24dp)
                      .setContentTitle(text)
                        .setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```